# Is there a way to make Haddock render per-argument docs for type class methods?

Tags: haskell, haddock

It turns out that Haddock does not render per-argument docs for type class
methods:

```haskell
class Foo a where

  foo
    :: Int -- ^ This string will be ignored by Haddock
    -> a
```

This causes certain issues for users of a library I maintain, because
the methods in my case have quite lengthy signatures. I have always had the descriptions in
the source formatted like that (certainly works for ordinary functions), but
it turns out Haddock does not display them (and does not complain about them
either).

Is there a way to display the per-argument docs with Haddock? Some workaround perhaps?

Comment: Are you open to making a major API change? If so, I could write a short answer on how to use a [single record argument](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/haskell-anti-pattern-incremental-ad-hoc-parameter-abstraction/) for this.

Comment: With Haddock 2.16.1, I get the per-argument doc rendered just fine, for standalone functions as well as for class methods.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I'm running through 2.17.1, this: https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/blob/master/Text/Megaparsec.hs#L572-L575 for example, no per-argument docs. Can you spot a difference in markup, or is it a regression?

Comment: @DanielWagner, Major changes are possible, but they should not make the API emm... stylized just for the sake of a bit better docs. I'd like to keep it simple.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, Just confirmed, works with Haddock 2.16.1 but not with 2.17.1. Looks like a regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this was a regression. This thing should work (and worked in version 2.16.1), but stopped (2.17.1 and later).

I have reported this: https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/647, should be fixed in version 2.18 (you can see there is a PR for this already).